# What does hypolithial mean

Tags: zoology, literature

I'm writing a thesis in biology and my supervisor asked me to find literature about beetles living under rocks - specifically she wants me to find something about hypolithial diversity. However Google doesn't even recognize the word 'hypolithial' so I'm kind of stranded without any references on where to start searching.

I know that hypo lithia comes from ancient greek and means below stones, but nobody mentioned it like that in the literature.

Has anybody heard of this term or knows a similar one which I could use for my research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google for sublithic or hypolithic.

You'll find lots of things like (https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-3-642-11274-4_767) with further references and links

Comment: [Scholar provides some useful results.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&q=hypolithic).